# Proving the identity ${n \choose k} = {\sum\limits_{m=k-1}^{n-1} {m \choose k-1}}$ by induction over t=n-k

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, induction

Of the identity ${n \choose k} = {\sum\limits_{m=k-1}^{n-1} {m \choose k-1}}$, a proof by induction over $d=n-k$ should be possible. I can only see how $${n+1 \choose k} = {n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1}$$ (by Pascal's identity)

$$ ={\sum_{m=k-1}^{n-1} {m \choose k-1}} + {n \choose k-1}$$   (by induction hypothesis) $$={\sum_{m=k-1}^{n} {m \choose k-1}}$$ 
leads to the result. Can someone point me into the right direction for an induction over $d=n-k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $d=n-k$, you can rewrite it as

$$\binom{d+k}k=\sum_{m=k-1}^{d+k-1}\binom{m}{k-1}\;;$$

let $\ell=m-(k-1)$, and this can in turn be rewritten

$$\binom{d+k}k=\sum_{\ell=0}^d\binom{\ell+k-1}{k-1}\;,$$

and you want to prove this by induction on $d$. Just use the same approach that you took for your induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for an inductive proof, but I cannot resist a combinatorial proof when the opportunity presents itself.

The lefthand side, $\binom{n}{k}$, counts the number of $k$-element subsets of the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. Partition the collection of all such subsets according to their largest element. I will demonstrate.

The number of $k$-element subsets whose largest element is $k$ is $\binom{k-1}{k-1}$; choose $k-1$ elements from the set $\{1, 2, \dots, k-1\}$ and then include the element $k$. (This can be done in only one way, of course.)

The number of $k$-element subsets whose largest element is $k+1$ is $\binom{k}{k-1}$; choose $k-1$ elements from the set $\{1, 2, \dots, k\}$ and then include the element $k+1$.

In general, the number of $k$-element subsets whose largest element is $m+1$ is $\binom{m}{k-1}$; choose $k-1$ elements from the set $\{1, 2, \dots, m\}$ and then include the element $m+1$. Summing over $m$ gives the desired identity.

Comment: Well, thank you for yielding to the temptation. I am always looking for more exposure to the diverse ways to shed light onto a mathematical problem. Just wanted to leave you my gratitude :)